# Application freezes on exit - how to debug?

Tags: delphi, freeze

We have an application made up by a host (exe) and a lot of modules (dlls) containing gui etc.
Sometimes, the application freezes on shutdown. Mostly it happens during testing through TestComplete. We are not able to reproduce the behavior during debugging.

**How can we find out why the application freezes?**

I would guess that it is related to threads, but I do not know for sure.

Are there any tools or techniques we should try out?

Comment: Can't this be a bug in TestComplete?

Comment: If it *mostly* happens while testing with TestComplete, then it *sometimes* happens while *not* using TestComplete, so it's probably not a bug in TestComplete, @Workshop.

Comment: When TestComplete increases the number of times that the freeze occurs then it's probably a timing issue. It then seems to be a race condition, possibly related to a critical section or other resources that are used. Question is, is there anything in your code that could cause such race conditions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that good old logging would help you. Add some logging to every unit `finalization`, add such logging to destructors of global data (database connection, global configuration etc). Of course do not destroy logger object.

If your application is multithreaded then add some logging to working threads such as writing '[date] thread [name of class] working' and write it every few seconds (you can use some debug mode). Also add logging when thread discovers that it should terminate.

Also use some system utilites such as ProcessMonitor, Handles, Process Explorer (all by Sysinternals/Microsoft). Monitor disk reads/writes, handle count, memory usage, network connections. Maybe your application dumps some big structures on disk at exit? Maybe it allocated a lot of memory and must release it?

Comment: Well said. Strongly seconded.

Comment: When using D2010 you can see in the debugger if a certain Thread is waiting for another Thread that might be helpfull as well.

Answer (score 5):

Rig it with [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/) or [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/), and that may show you where the exception is, or where the memory leak is that is causing the exception.  Both of those are excellent tools with fully-featured trial versions.  Try 'em, buy 'em.  Good stuff.

Comment: Is it likely to be caused by a exception? We already use ExceptionMagic, but I guess MadExcept or EurekaLog would give more informasjon.

Comment: MadExcept is a good choice, we've been using it for years. Life-saver in uncountable situations. For your problem, once you managed to reproduce it, I recommend using madTraceProcess (comes with madExcept). It will get you the callstacks of each thread. Do that a few times while the app is frozen - and you should get an idea about the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the debugger's presence keeps the problem from occurring, then wait for the problem to occur, and *then* attach the debugger to it. Pause execution and you can inspect each thread's call stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you use lots of GUI components in DLL's and/or do plenty of multi-threading then you'd first have to discover which DLL or thread is causing the problem. Or maybe it's a combination of both. Basically, you should create log events for every DLL and thread that gets loaded/started. Try to get a situation where you have a minimum of DLL's and threads loaded to generate the freeze. Then you've localized the problem to one of those.
Also, create simple test-applications or use a unit-testing framework to test specific modules. For example, there is a [Delphi version](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/) of [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) available, which might help. (It's called [DUnit](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/)...) Such a test framework is helpful to isolate the threads and DLL's to check each of them.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is happenning under windows 7 and there are threads running in DLL, you must shutdown/terminate all running DLL threads before closing the main form of executable.

Good luck